# problema con el codigo html y css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-tabla, table

nose si alguien me podria ayudar con un problema que tengo. Estoy haciendo un emailing y a la hora de crear las tablas y poner una de ellas me crea un hueco entre uno de los cortes y nose muy bien por que. En este caso seria el ultimo tr que se puede ver en el codigo el que me crear el corte, si lo quito ese corte desaparece y se ve la imagen completa. Creo que lo crea la etiqueta a`

```
<tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-0.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-1.png" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-2.png" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-3.png" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-4.png" /></td>
    </tr>







<tr>
    <td > </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Las celdas de tablas no son elementos de bloque, los espacios antes de cada imagen son visibles `<td> <img ...></td>`, quítalos para que las imágenes no se separen. Y, como te sugieren en una respuesta, agrega `colspan` en la celda del enlace, para que ocupe todo el espacio horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

intenta agregar un colspan a la td

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">
    <a href="https://gacetadental.com/emailing/dental/20210323/3326/index.html"  target="_blank">
      Si no ve correctamente este e-mail puede hacer click aquí
    </a> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La solución fue tal y como me dijiste. Muchsisimas gracias

Comment: @Aitorm, si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta cerrar un tr, me parece que deberia ser:

```
<tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-0.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-0.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-1.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-1.png" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-2.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-2.png" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-3.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-3.png" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-0-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-1-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-2-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-3-4.png" /></td>
        <td> <img src="../ultra/img_ultra/ultra copia-4-4.png" /></td>
    </tr>


</tr>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por todo